# Help identifying 1970's American movie about aliens who cause people to commit mass suicide

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I remember watching an American (I believe) movie in the 1970s about aliens coming to Earth and psychically causing mass suicides. The movie may have been made in the late 60s or early 70s as I watched it on TV in 70s. (On channel 50 in Detroit, if that helps.)

I don't remember any of the actors, as I was fairly young when I watched it.

I believe the main action was set in New York City, or some other large city. I don't think the aliens landed on Earth, but they did sometimes abduct people. I remember a scene where an elderly man has been abducted and is returned to Earth where he's questioned about what happened. He tells them that he met an attractive young woman and implies that they had sex. (I have a vague memory of them showing some of their interactions, and the woman being a tall white woman with very long black hair in a tight pony tail.)

Throughout the movie, people all over are committing suicide for what seems like no reason (if I recall correctly). That's most of what I remember.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like [Starship Invasions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Invasions) from 1977 with Robert Vaughn and Christopher Lee in a silly hat.

> The plot concerns the black-clad Legion of the Winged Serpent, a rogue group of human-like telepathic aliens led by Captain Rameses (Christopher Lee). The Legion's home planet Alpha in the Orion constellation is about to be destroyed in the imminent supernova of its star, and Rameses is leading a small force of flying saucers to Earth to examine its suitability for their race. Performing several alien abductions, they discover they are descendants of transplanted humans, and thus the Earth is perfect for them. They plan to make way for themselves after killing everyone through the use of a device whose **signals prompt people to commit suicide.**

It starts with the scene you described: An old farmer is abducted and taken aboard a UFO where he's seduced by a nude alien brunette. He later describes it to a cop and admits they had sex. The movie is currently available in its entirety on Youtube. Here's the trailer: